# SAS: update with join?

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to update values of test1.control_s from table `test_ctrl.control_s`.

I am using this code:

```
proc sql;

update test1
set control_s= (select control_s 
from test_ctrl
inner join test1
on test1.custno=test_ctrl.custno
and test1.accno=test_ctrl.accno);

quit;
```

I am dealing with million records. I have to use join but I am not able to.

Comment: Removed the mysql tag since if you're working on SAS you'll need SAS SQL unless you can use SQL Pass Through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to join, you just use a correlated subquery.

```
proc sql;

update test1
set control_s= (select control_s 
from test_ctrl
where test1.custno=test_ctrl.custno
and test1.accno=test_ctrl.accno);

quit;
```

Here's an example using `sashelp.class`:

```
data class;
  set sashelp.class;
  height=0;
run;

data ht_data;
  set sashelp.class;
  keep name height;
run;

proc sql;
  update class
  set height = (
    select height from ht_data
    where ht_Data.name = class.name
  );
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you Joe...

I used without join and it takes long time to process.. so was wondering if i can add join to reduce time?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  What you may want to do is an an `WHERE EXISTS` if it is relatively uncommon for there to be a match.